# Why is my title of my pages not positioned correctly?

Tags: html, css

I have a component named ***admin.component***, in this component, I have a menu and a header.

[image]

In fact, when I create a new page, for example: the **currency** page.

The title is at the bottom of the la page, I don't understand why?

Normally, the title must be at the top...

[image]

I think that the component ***admin.component.html*** isnt't correct?

```
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class="bx bxl-c-plus-plus"></i>
      <span class="logo_name">Menu</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a routerLink="value" class="active">
          <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
          <span class="links_name">Value</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="currency">
          <i class="bx bx-box"></i>
          <span class="links_name">Currency</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
    <nav>
      <div class="sidebar-button">
        <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
        <span class="dashboard">Dashboard</span>
      </div>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        <i class="bx bx-search"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-details">
        <span class="admin_name">Prem Shahi</span>
        <i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </section>
```

For the ***currency.component.html*** page, I have this:

```
<div class="home-content">
  <h1 style="text-align: center">Currency Page</h1>
</div>
```

The code is available [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x1fumz?file=src/styles.css), if you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now need to change in **admin.component.html**  with below stracture and resolved issue easily

```
<router-outlet>
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class="bx bxl-c-plus-plus"></i>
      <span class="logo_name">Menu</span>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li>
        <a routerLink="value" class="active">
          <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
          <span class="links_name">Value</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a routerLink="currency">
          <i class="bx bx-box"></i>
          <span class="links_name">Currency</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <section class="home-section">
    <nav>
      <div class="sidebar-button">
        <i class="bx bx-menu sidebarBtn"></i>
        <span class="dashboard">Dashboard</span>
      </div>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
        <i class="bx bx-search"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="profile-details">
        <span class="admin_name">Prem Shahi</span>
        <i class="bx bx-chevron-down"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </section>
</router-outlet>
```

only add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` after `</nav>` tag and check upper code so you will get idea how to implement

Top Header is now fixed and only content will be change like below ss
[image]
[image]